# Lumen 5.5 unit-test post json

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, lumen

learning Lumen v5.5 php framework and have hit a roadblock creating my first php unit test. The app works using Postman if I set the URL and select POST method and in the body choose "raw" and set the type to "application/json". So we already know the post works, just looking to crate a test.

Here is the closest thing to what i think a working unit test should be:

```
public function testPostJson() {
    $the_json    = '{"client_guid": "C00A0EA5-3F64-01EA-C4B6-159EA145AB3B"}';
    $the_headers = [ 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json' ];
    $this->call(
        'POST',
        '/getClientNotes',
        [],
        [],
        [],
        $the_headers,
        $the_json
    );
    $this->assertResponseOk();
    $this->assertEquals(true, $this->response->status);
}
```

But of course it returns errors like:

- 1) NotesTest::testPostJson Expected status code 200, got 404.*
- 2) ErrorException: Undefined property:
  Illuminate\Http\Response::$status

Not much in the way of documentation even at the lumen docs site: 
https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/testing

Comment: Is the route created for POST or GET? getClientNotes sounds like a GET request.

Comment: no, not a get its POST here is the route: $app->post('note/getClientNotes',    'NoteController@getClientNotes');

Comment: well crap, there is my first mistake...   '/getClientNotes',  should be 'note'/getClientNotes',

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the working code... I was missing the "note/" in the 2nd parameter of the $this->call().

```
class NotesTest extends TestCase {

protected $send_headers = null;
protected $send_json = null;
protected $receive_json = null;

public function testIsApiAlive() {
    $this->call("GET",'/');
    $this->assertEquals($this->app->version(), $this->response->getContent());
    $this->assertEquals(200, $this->response->status());
}

public function testPostJson() {
    $this->send_json    = '{"client_guid": "C00A0EA5-3F64-01EA-C4B6-159EA145AB3B"}';
    $this->send_headers = [ 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json' ];
    $this->call(
        'POST',
        'note/getClientNotes',
        [],
        [],
        [],
        $this->send_headers,
        $this->send_json
    );
    $this->receive_json = json_decode($this->response->getContent());
    $this->assertEquals(200, $this->response->status());
    $this->assertTrue(isset($this->receive_json->status));
    $this->assertTrue($this->receive_json->status == true);
    $this->assertTrue(isset($this->receive_json->data[0]->agency));
    $this->assertTrue($this->receive_json->data[0]->agency == 'demo');
}
```

Here is the command line results :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\jsonproject\tests\>phpunit NotesTest.php
PHPUnit 5.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 740 ms, Memory: 10.00MB

OK (2 tests, 7 assertions)
```